# JSON Parse error undefined variable u in the beggning / can not read subSubItems${i} while repeater data has values

Tags: javascript, json, wix, velo

I am kinda new to the Velo coding / javascript in general and I am trying to re-create this tutorial --> https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-tutorial-creating-an-expanding-mega-menu
Without the second menu (only a main menu and a strip with the items like attached screenshot).
I have a problem with javascript and wix coding. Even though I have created the collections correctly for some reason I can not open the site menu correctly. I am also attaching a wix forum link: https://www.wix.com/velo/forum/coding-with-velo/typeerror-cannot-read-properties-of-undefined-reading-filter.

Can not read the data `subSubItems{i}` from repeaterData, while it has all the necessary data in it
I am also attaching a screenshot of the database inself for review. (Json format on subSubItems) and the wix site itself as of right now: https://giannisliko.wixsite.com/my-site-1

[image: database]
[image: repeaterData_fixed]

The global page coding is this:

```
// The code in this file will load on every page of your site
//-------------Imports-------------//
import wixData from 'wix-data';
//-------------Global Variables-------------//

//Number of Submenu 2 repeaters.
const subLevel2RepeaterCount = 5;

//Object containing all menu data from subTitles database collection.
let menuData;

$w.onReady(async () => {
    
  //Get the menu data from the collection.
  menuData = await wixData.query("SubTitlesCollection").find().then(result => result.items);
  //console.log(menuData);
  //Set up each Submenu 2 repeater as it is loaded.
  for (let i = 1; i <= subLevel2RepeaterCount; i++) {
    $w(`#repeaterSubSub${i}`).onItemReady(($item, itemData, index) => {
      //Get the repeater button from its ID.
      const repeaterButton = $item(`#buttonSubLevelTwo${i}`)
      //Set the item label.
      repeaterButton.label = itemData.label;
      //Set the item link.
      repeaterButton.link = itemData.url;
    });
  }
});


export function buttonMainMenu_mouseIn(event) {
    //Get the ID of the Submenu 1 button the mouse hovers over.
    const selectedRootId = event.context.itemId;
 //Get all the data of the Submenu 2 related to Submenu 1.
    const repeaterData = menuData.filter(item => item.menu === selectedRootId);
   const repeaterData2 = menuData.filter(item => item._id === selectedRootId);
   console.log(repeaterData2);
 //Set up the box element corresponding to the selected button in Submenu 2.
    setSubSubMenu(repeaterData); 
 //Show the Submenu 2 box.
    $w('#megaMenuStrip').expand();
}



export function repeaterMainMenu_mouseOut(event) {
    
}


function createUniqueId() {
 //Creating a Unique Id for each of the menu sub-items by getting the current millisecond and adding a random number from 1 to 1000
 let id = String(+new Date() + Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000))
 return id;
}


function setSubSubMenu(repeaterData) {
 //Set the image of the Submenu 1
 //$w('#rangeMenuImage').src = repeaterData.img1;
 for (let i = 1; i <= subLevel2RepeaterCount; i++) {
  //Convert the Submenu 2 string to a Javascript object.
  console.log(repeaterData);
  console.log(repeaterData[`subSubItems1`]);
  const dataSubSub = JSON.parse(repeaterData[`subSubItems${i}`]);
  //Set a unique ID for each item.
  console.log(dataSubSub);
  dataSubSub.forEach(subSubItem => {
   subSubItem._id = createUniqueId();
  })
  //Set the Submenu 2 data in the repeater.
  $w(`#repeaterSubSub${i}`).data = dataSubSub;
 }
}


export function megaMenuStrip_mouseOut(event) {
    $w('#megaMenuStrip').collapse();
}

/**
*   Adds an event handler that runs when the mouse pointer is moved
 onto the element.

 You can also [define an event handler using the Properties and Events panel](https://support.wix.com/en/article/velo-reacting-to-user-actions-using-events).
    [Read more](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w.Element.html#onMouseIn)
*    @param {MouseEvent} event
*/


/**
*   Sets the function that runs when a new repeated item is created.
    [Read more](https://www.wix.com/corvid/reference/$w.Repeater.html#onItemReady)
*    @param {$w} $item
*/
```

**Thank you very much in advance**

Comment: Can you log what `repeaterData` is before the problematic line, so we can get a better idea of what is going on?

Comment: Hello Sam, Yes I did that before sorry I forgot to mention I get "undefined"

Answer (score 1):

I can't say for sure what's going on, but I can try to point you in the right direction.

If `repeaterData` is `undefined`, that means something is probably going wrong  on the following line:

```
const repeaterData = menuData.filter(item => item._id === selectedRootId)[0]
```

The problem there could be that `menuData` is undefined, which would mean your query is no good.

Or it could be that none of the item IDs match the `selectedRootId`. I'm guessing that is the case. Looks like in the tutorial they aren't try to match with `item._id` like you are doing. It's really hard to tell exactly what's wrong there, but I'm pretty sure that's where your issue is. It could be a problem with your repeater IDs or it could be with the data coming from the collection. Either way, you're not getting any matches there.

Comment: Thank you for your help I am trying to figure it out based on ur comments, I am gonna let you know

Comment: For the menuData im getting items correctly as follows: 
Array(28)jsonTableCopy JSON
0: {...}jsonTableCopy JSON
subSubItems1: "[{\"label\":\"T-Shirts\",\"url\":\"https://giannisliko.wixsite.com/my-site-1/sale\"}]"
menu: "a9d1a767-dc8a-4fb3-bb62-d0d503da6978"
_id: "eac10850-3de2-4f50-b38f-f21b6b29d7a1"

Comment: What shoud I be getting from event.context.itemId, because I think i should be getting an id matching the id of the database but instead i get : "item1".

Comment: Okey I fixed a lot of things, now repeater data gets the correct data, did some logging and working on your proposal above, but now I am getting an error on JSON parse about "undefined symbol u". Working on it